# how to put two navbar-collapse content in same line

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to navbar-collapse content. All I want to display these contents in same line (inline).

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-rt-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-mid-collapse">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="">My Project</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-mid-collapse">
                <form class="navbar-form form-inline" role="search" method="get" id="search-form" name="search-form">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">

                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-rt-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Output]

So, How to display #nabar-mid-collapse and #navbar-rt-collapse in the same line?
Thanks

Comment: Hope the updated answer helps..

Answer (score 2):

You need a little extra css and a tweak to your markup to get your desired result:

**CSS:**

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    width: 44px;
    height: 36px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse .navbar-form{
        margin: 0;
        border: 0 none;
    }
    .navbar-form .form-group {
        float: left;
        min-width: 80%;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: inline-block!important;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-rt-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-mid-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="">My Project</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-mid-collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-rt-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#">Register</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/3bnOBdLHve)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both `#nabar-mid-collapse` and `#navbar-rt-collapse` in a div with class `row-fluid`,

and apply class `col-xs-4` (*or any respective`.col` class according to the width you need for each item *) to both of them.

read more about the grid system section of [bootstrap css documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6806/)

Comment: There is no row-fluid in Bootstrap 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem and the answer from @jme11 gave me the idea to do this:

```
//multiple .navbar-collapse.collapse
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-collapse:after {
        clear:both;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse:after {
        clear:none;
    }
}
```

Hope that it helps people that come across this post.